# How should I create a timer in ros2?

Tags: ros2, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for the create_timer function in ros2 but I only find the rclcpp::Node::create_wall_timer.

From my understanding there should be some abstract create_timer function (instead of wall timer) to work optionally with the simulated time. Where is this function?

If that function is not there in ros2, what would be the solution to have some abstract timer that adapts to the wall or to the simulated time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362478/how-should-i-create-a-timer-in-ros2?/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2020-09-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an `rclcpp::create_timer()` free function

- [Foxy code](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/foxy/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/create_timer.hpp)
- [Foxy API documentation](http://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp/create__timer_8hpp.html)
  git
- [tf2_ros::BufferServer uses `rclcpp::create_timer()`](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/6788c1b78fe35e1a459a9d8f184afeb79792bd71/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/buffer_server.h#L95-L96)

The trick to a timer that uses simulated time is to pass a clock that uses simulated time to the `rclcpp::create_timer()` function. The [default clock on a node is a ROS clock](http://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Node.html#aec0332887ae90caed727e5025cb62195) - meaning it will use simulated time if simulated time is active.

You might also be interested in

- [ROS 2 Clock and Time design article](https://design.ros2.org/articles/clock_and_time.html)
- This very similar question #q354599

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2020-09-30**:
Correct. Thank you. Does anyone know why create_timer is a free function? and Node::create_wall_timer is a member function?

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-09-30**:
The free function has an advantage in that the same code can be used with both `LifecycleNode` and `Node`. There's some talk of making all functions free functions in https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/1259